# When is the global statement necessary?

Tags: python, reference, global, variable-assignment, shallow-copy

I am a little confused about "global" statement.

"sample code 1" runs ok without using "global" statement; however, "sample code 2" will not run unless the "global a" is un-commented.

Why do I have to declare "global" in "sample code 2" but not in "sample code 1"?

```
# sample code 1

def updating():    
    a.append(1);    

if __name__=='__main__':
    a=[100];
    print(f'before updating, variable a id is {id(a)}, and value is {a}')
    updating()
    print(f'after  updating, variable a id is {id(a)}, and value is {a}')
```

```
# sample code 2

def updating(): 
    #global a 
    a=a+[1]

if __name__=='__main__':
    a=[100];
    print(f'before updating, variable a id is {id(a)}, and value is {a}')
    updating()
    print(f'after  updating, variable a id is {id(a)}, and value is {a}')
```

Comment: code 1 only reads the variable, so it gets the global variable. code 2 assigns the variable, which makes it local.

Comment: Why to not read about `global` statement in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)?

Comment: do you suggest the assignment operator "=" determines whether global statement is necessary or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, an assignment to a name *always* operates on a local variable, creating a new one if it is not currently defined.

The `global` statement makes the name refer to a variable in the global scope, permitting you to assign to a global name without creating a new local variable.

(The `nonlocal` statement does something similar, except it makes the name refer to a variable defined in the closest enclosing scope, which is not necessarily the global scope.)

In your first example, you are not assigning to a name; you are performing attribute lookup on a free variable, which resolves to the global variable of the same name.

In your second example, you try to create a new local variable. Since scope is determined at compile time, `a = a + [1]` will fail, because the `a` on the right-hand side will still refer to the as-of-yet undefined local variable `a`. With `global`, the assignment does *not* create a local variable, so the right-hand side is an expression involving the global variable, and the result is assigned to the global name as well.

Comment: Kind of. `a[i] = 5` would also alter the global list without needing `global`, as it is not an assignment to a *name*.